# sql Null exception in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve images stored in SQL Server database into a datagrid view in vb.net, but I'm  getting an exception in the 4th line of the below code.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Please help me.

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand("select photo from stud_table", connection)
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
Dim table As New DataTable

Dim ImgStream As New MemoryStream(CType(command.ExecuteScalar, Byte()))

registerform1.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ImgStream)
adapter.Fill(table)

DataGridView1.DataSource = table
ImgStream.Dispose()

connection.Close()
```

Comment: This means that your photo column contains a NULL value and not the byte array. You should check with IsDbNull before using the value, but if it is possible to have null values in that column then you cannot pass directly the result of ExecuteScalar to the memory stream. Also remember that ExecuteScalar returns only the first column/first row and your query doesn't specify any WHERE clause

Comment: I see you have been on Stack Overflow for almost a year and asked several questions. You have not accepted any answers in all that time. Do you know that you are supposed to accept an answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer if an answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```vb
Dim ImgStream As New MemoryStream(CType(command.ExecuteScalar, Byte()))
```

do this:

```vb
Dim result = TryCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

If result IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim imgStream As New MemoryStream(result)

    'Use imgStream here.
End If
```

`TryCast` will return `Nothing` if the specified value cannot be cast as the specified type.

Note that you could also do this if desired:

```vb
Dim result = command.ExecuteScalar()

If result IsNot DBNull.Value Then
    Dim imgStream As New MemoryStream(DirectCast(result, Byte()))

    'Use imgStream here.
End If
```

Comment: I tried your code and the error is gone. But now it shows another error as: Parameter not valid in the line below:                        registerform1.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(imgStream)

Comment: Then the question you asked here is answered and the issue resolved and you now have a new issue that you can ask about in a new question.